# how do I extract all prices and give the min ? JSON request

Tags: python, json, python-requests

I'm trying to get the min price for the requested item.
I don't get how. Can anyone help?

```
import requests
import json


item = input('put your item here please :  ')
gg = item.replace(' ', '_')
response_url =  requests.get(f'https://api.warframe.market/v1/items/'+ gg +'/orders?include=item')

data = json.loads(response_url.text)
price = data['payload']['orders'][0]['platinum']

print(price)
```

here is an example url: https://api.warframe.market/v1/items/mirage_prime_systems/orders?include=item

Here's a small sample of the data from `data["payload"]["orders"]`:

```py
{'visible': True,
  'order_type': 'buy',
  'quantity': 1,
  'platinum': 11,
  'user': {'reputation': 4,
   'region': 'en',
   'avatar': 'user/avatar/60e52c93a4784b00c68db129.png?558d0a9d0e4627de50c4218bda527217',
   'last_seen': '2021-10-01T16:31:55.334+00:00',
   'ingame_name': 'WDNMDXZLL',
   'status': 'ingame',
   'id': '60e52c93a4784b00c68db129'},
  'platform': 'pc',
  'region': 'en',
  'creation_date': '2021-10-01T16:13:57.000+00:00',
  'last_update': '2021-10-01T16:13:57.000+00:00',
  'id': '615733c5db3f3b01febb45a4'},
 {'order_type': 'sell',
  'visible': True,
  'platinum': 19,
  'quantity': 1,
  'user': {'reputation': 0,
   'region': 'en',
   'last_seen': '2021-10-01T19:36:31.682+00:00',
   'ingame_name': 'Weshu',
   'avatar': 'user/avatar/5f775345d5551401da6e613f.png?38078a7a72b95c6a3f2b34319aea3e05',
   'status': 'ingame',
   'id': '5f775345d5551401da6e613f'},
  'platform': 'pc',
  'region': 'en',
  'creation_date': '2021-10-01T17:49:13.000+00:00',
  'last_update': '2021-10-01T17:49:13.000+00:00',
  'id': '61574a195af7c701d3bcbf74'},
```

we get lot of offers and lot of prices im trying to get min price of them all and display it !! thanks for help in advance

Comment: Please provide a sample of your response payload.

Comment: here u go brother https://api.warframe.market/v1/items/mirage_prime_systems/orders?include=item

Comment: Please provide a plain-text sample in your post.

Comment: Also please provide details the actual problem you're having.

Comment: brother its a large data we gonna get lot of slices from warframe game market i need to extract price and get min one for user

Comment: Do you want the minimum sell price or the minimum buy price? Or both?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't specify what you mean by "min price of them all" so I'll assume you want both the minimum buy price and the minimum sell price:

```py
orders = data["payload"]["orders"]
min_buy_price = min(o["platinum"] for o in orders if o["order_type"] == "buy")
min_sell_price = min(o["platinum"] for o in orders if o["order_type"] == "sell")
```